# Trazer Retorno entre duas functions - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, funções, return

Olá, tenho a fuction list , que traz um GET url em outra function..
 Como Eu faço pra obter o retorno de {data.name} fora da function list ?
Essa forma em baixo nao retorna :/

```js
function list(){

$.get( "<?php echo BASE_URL;?>/open/start/list", function( data ) {

data = typeof data == 'string' ? JSON.parse(data) : data;

return data.name;

});


}
//Trazer o retorno de data.name
console.log(list());
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não consegue porque o Ajax é assíncrono. Uma solução é usar um *callback* quando o `$.get` for processado:

```
function list(callback){
   $.get( "<?php echo BASE_URL;?>/open/start/list" ).done(function(data){
      data = typeof data == 'string' ? JSON.parse(data) : data;
      callback(data);
   });
}

//Trazer o retorno de data.name
list(function(data){ console.log(data.name) });
```

Comment: obrigado dvd, deu tudo certo aqui!